# Javascript replace all values in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

**Html:**

```
<textarea name="Editor" class="ckeditor" id="aboutme"></textarea>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.aboutme;
 var edata = editor.getData();


   for (var i = 0; i < edata.length; i++) {

var replaced_text = edata.replace(/(\[##.+?##\])/, '<span style="background-color:yellow"><strong>$1</strong></span>'); // you could also use a regex in the replace

editor.setData(replaced_text);
   }
```

If textarea has value like below,

```
"Textxx [##YellowText##] Textxxxx"
```

I replace [##YellowText##] to yellow background.I mean if text starts **[##** and finishes **##]** , i replace value with yellow background.

If i have value like below and if i run above javascript code , FirstText changes yellow background however SecondText or other textes never changes.

```
"[##FirstText##] [##SecondText##] [##AnothrText##] [##xxText##]"
```

I tried to use **"for"** however it did not work.

How can i change all text values if starts **[##** and finishes **##]** to yellow background in javascript ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the global (g) flag to your regex to replace all matched instances.

```
var replaced_text = edata.replace(/(\[##.+?##\])/g, '<span style="background-color:yellow"><strong>$1</strong></span>');
```

see flags:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

edit:

the main difference is 

`original: /(\[##.+?##\])/
modified: /(\[##.+?##\])/g`

Comment: how come i could not understand replaced_text should be out of function as global ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var replaced_text = edata.replace(/\[##(.+?)##\]/g, '<span style="background-color:yellow"><strong>$1</strong></span>');
```

Add the `g` after the final `/` of the regex to make the replacement global (i.e. happen across the whole text multiple times rather than the just the first occurance).

I've also changed the position of your capture group in your regex as I assumed you would't want to keep the `[##` and `##]` after the replacement.